# Web page Fonts change after locale has changed IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

In my webpage, it is Ok for presentation in Language English US. But our web application supports Locale.

When I use browser language English US, the web page can be viewed according to my css even I change default browser font.

But when I change to browser language Japanese(JP), the web page uses default browser font, not use my font in css.

Why is it occurred?? I wanna know how to modify it.

**PS:** 
I use IE8 where problem occurs, but in firefox 15.0.1 and chrome version 22.0, the problem does not occur.

Comment: Do you have a simple demo page on which the problem occurs? Maybe you can set one up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar.

Comment: @swemon, what do you mean by changing browser language?

Comment: Have you linked a custom Japanese font in the CSS?

Comment: Here is code in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mQpaF/2/ This is simple form of my code.  Please check it.

Comment: Was the font subsetted to ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, 
[CSS font property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp) said

> The font-size and font-family values are required. If one of the other
>   values are missing, the default values will be inserted, if any.

When I use **English locale**(change browser language to English), one of these fonts[arial,helvetica,clean,sans-serif] are available.
So my web page works fine.

But when I change to **Japanese locale**(change browser language to Japanese), none of these fonts used in my css are available. So browser default browser font is used. Whenever I change browser default font, my web page presentation is also changed.

**Correction** is to add a japanese font `MS PGothic` to my css. like

```
font-family: MS PGothic, Arial, sans-serif;
```

OR

```
html *
{
    font-family: MS PGothic !important;
}
```

So when browser language is japanese, `MS PGothic` is used. You can read CSS !important in 
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

This is my understanding and correction to my problem. Let me know if a better way exists.